# Convergence of the density of the sum of random variables with a parameter

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory

Let $X$ be a random variable with density and $N$ be the *standard normal distribution* such that $X$ and $N$. I wonder if $f_{X+tN}\to f_{X}$ as $t \to 0$, where $f$ denote the density functions.

By the independence, we have $f_{X+tN}=f_X*(tN)$. There seems to be a result in real analysis saying that $f*(tN)\to f$ in $L^p$, and it follows that there is a subsequence $\{t_n\}\to 0$ s.t. $f_X*(t_nN)\to f_X$. But is it possible to show that $f_{X+tN}\to f_{X} $a.e.?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  It is all very classical:
\begin{align}
(f_X*f_{tN})(x)-f_X(x)
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{tN}(x-s)[f_X(s)-f_X(x)]\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{x-\delta}f_{tN}(x-s)f_X(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&\quad -f_X(x)\int_{-\infty}^{x-\delta}f_{tN}(x-s)\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&\quad +\int_{x+\delta}^\infty f_{tN}(x-s)f_X(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&\quad -f_X(x)\int_{x+\delta}^\infty f_{tN}(x-s)\,\mathrm{d}s\\
&\quad +\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}f_{tN}(x-s)[f_X(s)-f_X(x)]\,\mathrm{d}s\\
\end{align}
and each integral $\to 0$ and $t\downarrow 0$ if $x$ is a Lebesgue point of $f_X$: the first four $\to 0$ are easy consequence of $f_{tN}$ decaying expontially in $t$ outside $[-\delta,\delta]$, and the last integral follows from $f_X$ is approximately constant.

**Edit**

To bound the last integrand, integrate by parts gives
$$
f_{tN}(\delta)\bigg[F_X(x+\delta)-F_X(x-\delta)-2\delta f(x)\bigg]
+\int_{x-\delta}^{x+\delta}f'_{tN}(x-s)\Big[F_X(s)-(s-x)f_X(x)\Big]\,\mathrm{d}s
$$
The boundary term poses no problem when $t\downarrow 0$.
Since $f_{tN}$ is even, $f'_{tN}$ is odd, so the remaining integral is
$$
\int_0^\delta f'_{tN}(-h)\Big[F_X(x+h)-F_X(x-h)-2hf_X(x)\Big]\,\mathrm{d}h.
$$
Note that $x$ being Lebesgue point of $f_X$ gives
$$
\lvert F_X(x+h)-F_X(x-h)-2hf_X(x)\rvert\leq h\varepsilon(h),\quad \varepsilon(h)\downarrow 0\text{ as }h\downarrow 0
$$
allowing us to bound the integral
\begin{multline}
\left\lvert\int_0^\delta f'_{tN}(-h)\Big[F_X(x+h)-F_X(x-h)-2hf_X(x)\Big]\,\mathrm{d}h\right\rvert\\
\leq
\varepsilon(\delta)\int_0^\delta f'_{tN}(-h)h\,\mathrm{d}h
\end{multline}
and
$$
\int_0^\delta f'_{tN}(-h)h\,\mathrm{d}h\leq\int_{-\infty}^\infty f'_{tN}(-h)h\,\mathrm{d}h\leq\int_{-\infty}^\infty f_{tN}(h)h^2\,\mathrm{d}h\leq 1
$$
for $t\leq 1$.  So we are done.

Comment: Did you really use your assumption that $x$ is a Lebesgue point? I don't see something like $\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)} \!|f(y)-f(x)|\,\mathrm{d}y=0$?

Comment: Yes, to bound the integral of factor $f_X(s)-f_X(x)$ on $[x-\delta,x+\delta]$ for small enough $\delta$ when I say "$f_X$ is approximately constant".  Perhaps I should spell this out a little more.